# Getting Array with MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, autocomplete, mydbr

I have a form with the fields **Name**, **Email**, and **City**. **City** is an autocomplete field that calls 3 separate tables (Cities, Regions, Countries).

[image: city field]

What I'd like to do is to have these explode into an array so that City, Region, and Country are all defined values. This is my query right now for the autocomplete field:

```
   SELECT c.City, concat(r.Region, ', ', co.Country)
   FROM Cities c, Regions r, Countries co
   WHERE c.RegionID = r.RegionID and c.CountryID = co.CountryID and c.City like CONCAT( inCity, '%' )
   ORDER BY City;
```

As you can see, the entered value (**inCity**) is only compared to the City column in the Cities table.

The reason I need to have the City, Region, and Country defined is because I need to enter their IDs in another table called **Events**. This is my query to insert the CityID into my **Events** table:

```
   INSERT INTO Events (Events.CityID)
   VALUES ((SELECT CityID FROM Cities WHERE City = inCity LIMIT 1));
```

This also doesn't work because sometimes there are multiple cities with the same name.

I was able to do this before with PHP, but I'm currently using myDBR reports to do this and I can only use queries.

Comment: Can't you just remove the concat?  Like this: SELECT c.City, r.Region, co.Country

Comment: @JoelLewiw - I could, but I have it like that so that they're all shown as one line in the autocomplete form. And even if I remove concat, I still don't know how to call Region & Country in my INSERT query.

Answer (score 0):

Things are a lot clearer when you keep your `JOIN` conditions out of your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT concat(c.City, ', ', r.Region, ', ', co.Country)
FROM Cities c
    INNER JOIN Regions r ON c.RegionID = r.RegioID
    INNER JOIN Countries co ON c.CountryID = co.CountryID
WHERE c.City like CONCAT( inCity, '%' )
ORDER BY City;
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. I'm still confused about how to get the Region & Country in my INSERT query though.

Comment: If this answer fixed it, can you mark it as accepted, please? If not, you should add your own answer, for future reference.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I changed my query to what you provided to make things clearer, but I still have the same problem (can't get call the Region & Country in my INSERT query)